# Video views are not being counted on mobile

Tags: laravel, html5-video, bootstrap-modal

I have a project where I count the number of times a video was viewed. But I notice that the video view is not being counted on mobile and the modal is not showing but instead the video automatically goes to full screen. I have my code here can someone take a look at it to see what I am doing wrong? I will be adding comments so you that you can understand what's going on.

```
    /*This the video once the video is click it opens to a modal and the 
     video automatically plays.
  */
   <video class="video1" id="cx" preload="auto" align="middle" data- 
   toggle="modal"  data-target="#mymodal" data-user-id="{{$users->id}}"
            data-video-src="{{$users->intro_video}}"
            data-video-views="{{$users->clicks}}" style="  
       cursor:pointer;  "><source  src="{{$users->intro_video}}#t=15" 
      playsinline alt="Video Unavailable"   id="" ></source>
     </video>

   //This the modal
   <div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-12">
<div id="mymodal" class="modal fade" role="dialog" style="padding- 
 top:3%;">
      <h1 class="close" data-dismiss="modal" style="color:white; 
 position:relative; right:20px;">X</h1>

<div class="modal-dialog">
<!--modal content-->

<div class="modal-content" style="align-items: center;">

<div class="modal-body" style=" height:300px; width:100%; 
 background:black; display:flex; justify-content: center;">
   <video  class="video2" id="video_source" src="" preload="auto" 
 align="middle" style="  
       cursor:pointer;  " autoplay="true">
  </video>
</div>
  </div>

  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

  //This is my controller where it will increment the click every time the 
  video is click

 public function index(Request $request){
    $requested_id=$request->input('requested_id');
     $video = User::where('id', $requested_id)->increment('clicks');



   }

//Last but not least this is javascript for the ajax request
once the modal shows the request is going to be sent to increment the video count

$('#mymodal').on('show.bs.modal show', function (event) {

    var button = $(event.relatedTarget);


    var user_id = button.data('user-id') ;
    var video_src = button.data('video-src');
    var video_views = button.data('video-views');


    var modal = $(this);
    modal.find('#video_source').attr('src', video_src);
    modal.find('#video_views').text(video_views);

    // send ajax request to increment video count. Just send request_id
    $.ajax({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'getmsg',
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data : {
            requested_id: user_id
        },
        success: function(data){

        }
    });
})
```

Comment: have you tried adding the `playsinline` attribute to the `<video...>` tag to stop it going fullscreen?

Comment: Hello @Offbeatmammal Thanks for replying. I did it's in the code

Comment: @Offbeatmammal I didn't have playsinline on there. I had put in the <source> tag. But I have one problem I have to click it again then it goes  to full screen and then it plays.

Comment: my guess would be Bootstrap isn't opening the modal on mobile? perhaps it's defaulting to play video fullscreen. Rather than put the counter on the modal opening, can you hook it onto the video play event (just record the first time it plays then cancel the handler)

Comment: @Offbeatmammal oh ok I see what you're saying. After looking over my code I found the solution the playsinline was the answer Thank you for that answer and I also had to edit my code,I didn't display it on the question but I fixed that part. Thank you for helping me!